# Executing shell script on Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, ffmpeg, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to encode .mp4 videos into hls using FFmpeg.

I am using `subprocess` to call FFmpeg:

```
def transcoder(data, context):
    """Background Cloud Function to be triggered by Cloud Storage.
       This generic function logs relevant data when a file is changed.

    Args:
        data (dict): The Cloud Functions event payload.
        context (google.cloud.functions.Context): Metadata of triggering event.
    Returns:
        None; the output is written to Stackdriver Logging
    """
    try:
        input_filename = data['name'].split('/')[-1] #videos have no extension
        input_path = f'/tmp/{input_filename}'
        print(f'filename {input_filename}')
        print(f'input_path {input_path}')
        print(f"bucket {data['bucket']}")
        print(f"name {data['name']}")

        outdir_path = f'/tmp/output/{input_filename}'
        os.makedirs(outdir_path, exist_ok=True)

        bucket = client.get_bucket(data['bucket'])
        blob = bucket.get_blob(data['name'])
        blob.download_to_filename(input_path)

        cmd = f'''ffmpeg -y -i {input_path} \
              -preset ultrafast -g 60 -sc_threshold 0 \
              -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 \
              -s:v:0 360x640 -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 365k \
              -s:v:1 720x1280 -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 3000k \
              -c:a copy \
              -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1" \
              -master_pl_name master.m3u8 \
              -f hls -hls_time 6 -hls_list_size 0 \
              -hls_segment_filename "{outdir_path}/%v_fileSequence%d.ts" \
              -hls_playlist_type vod \
               {outdir_path}/%v_prog_index.m3u8'''

        process = subprocess.Popen(cmd)
        stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
        upload_local_directory_to_gcs(outdir_path, upload_bucket, input_filename)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

The problem is that I get an error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'ffmpeg -y -i /tmp/video -preset ultrafast -g 60 -sc_threshold 0 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -s:v:0 360x640 -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 365k -s:v:1 720x1280 -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 3000k -c:a copy -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1" -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -f hls -hls_time 6 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename "/tmp/output/video/%v_fileSequence%d.ts" -hls_playlist_type vod /tmp/output/video/%v_prog_index.m3u8': 'ffmpeg -y -i /tmp/video -preset ultrafast -g 60 -sc_threshold 0 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -s:v:0 360x640 -c:v:0 libx264 -b:v:0 365k -s:v:1 720x1280 -c:v:1 libx264 -b:v:1 3000k -c:a copy -var_stream_map "v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1" -master_pl_name master.m3u8 -f hls -hls_time 6 -hls_list_size 0 -hls_segment_filename "/tmp/output/video/%v_fileSequence%d.ts" -hls_playlist_type vod /tmp/output/video/%v_prog_index.m3u8'
```

But I know that the input files and the output files do exist because I debugged that using `print(os.listdir(path))` so now I am wondering if the FFmpeg I call with subprocess has access to the /tmp folder..?

I know that there is a Python FFmpeg library I could use, but I don't know how to run my FFmpeg command using that library. Can you help?

p.s. I can run this locally with success.

Comment: Dont forget to pipe `stderr` and `stdout` like this `process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)`. If you're not doing this stderr and stdout will always be null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error occurs because you should split your command. [subprocess docs](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)

```py
from subprocess import Popen

# working fine
Popen('ffmpeg')

# crashing
Popen('ffmpeg -h')

# working fine
Popen('ffmpeg -h'.split())
```

Be careful, `"v:0,a:0 v:1,a:1"` this would not be parsed as intended, you will need to split the command manually.

Comment: I can run this command locally with success. So the problem lies with running this on google cloud functions.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's the problem in your GCF cause the error is `[Errno 2] No such file or directory` which means that python is having an error, not ffmpeg. In the case of a ffmpeg `no such file error`, the error would be in stderr as bytes.

Comment: Ah it could be! GCP is unix and locally I am using Windows. I will give it a try! thanks